# Appending to ObjectOutputStream does not change anything

Tags: android, file, kotlin, fileinputstream

Here's my problem. In my DetailActivity I check to see whether a File is empty or not. If it is, I create a new File and write an object to that file no problem. If it isn't, this means the file has a List of data objects written to it like so:

```
try{
      val file = File(filesDir, "Example Shelf")
      val outputStream = openFileOutput(file.name, Context.MODE_APPEND)
      if(file.length() != 0.toLong()){
           val inputStream = openFileInput(file.name)
           gameDetailViewModel.addGameToExistingShelf(outputStream, inputStream, data)
      } else {
           file.createNewFile()
           gameDetailViewModel.addGameToNewShelf(outputStream, data)
      } catch(...)
```

If the File has an object written to it, I want to essentially append a new data object to that List. To do that, I read the file, assign the List I read from the file to a new variable and then re-write it to the file.

```
fun addGameToExistingShelf(fos: FileOutputStream, fis: FileInputStream, data: GameData){
        val previousList = ObjectInputStream(fis).readObject() as MutableList<GameData>
        val newList = previousList
        newList.add(data)
        ObjectOutputStream(fos).writeObject(newList)
        fos.close()
        fis.close()
}
```

**The problem**: once the File has been written to, I want to read it from another Activity so I can display it in a RecyclerView. But when I read the File, it doesn't include any of the data objects added to the `newList` I recently wrote into the file. It only includes the data objects in the `previousList`, which is stale data by this point.

```
val file = File(filesDir, "Example Shelf")
if(file.isFile && file.length() != 0.toLong()){
  val inputStream = openFileInput(file.name)
  shelfViewModel.fetchShelfData(inputStream)
}
```

*ShelfViewModel.fetchShelfData*

```
fun fetchShelfData(fis: FileInputStream){
    val objis = ObjectInputStream(fis)
    //MutableLiveData<List<GameData>>
    shelfData.value = objis.readObject() as List<GameData>
    objis.close()
}
```

What is happening here? I've spent hours trying to debug this to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Close the outputstream before you open an inputstream.

Comment: @blackapps Altered the code so that each stream was closed before another was opened. Nothing has changed. After some further debugging, I've definitely nailed it down to the ``ObjectOutputStream(fos).writeObject(newList)`` not actually writing to the file. I just can't determine why it's not writing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading, I discovered it's not possible to append data to an already existing file because `ObjectOutputStream` adds a header to any and all writes it makes to a file.

Calling `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(data)` multiple times on the same file will result in a corrupted file due to the presence of multiple headers. When `ObjectInputStream` subsequently reads the file, it isn't smart enough to parse out all the extra stuff that gets written onto the file (such as the header). Refer [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)) for documentation.

To get around this, I simply recreated a new file using `file.createNewFile()` and wrote the new data to it. Because the file was essentially "recreated", all the header information from previous writes no longer exist - it is a blank file with the same name.

```
if(file.length() != 0.toLong()){
   val fileInput = openFileInput(file.name)
   val newData = gameDetailViewModel.fetchDataFromExistingShelf(fileInput, data)
   file.createNewFile() //File is recreated
   val fileOutput = openFileOutput(file.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   gameDetailViewModel.writeObjectToFile(fileOutput, newData) //Object is written to new, recreated file
```

Given I spent several hours trying to debug this, I hope this manages to help someone later down the track!